# UK Spousal Settlement Visa Denied - Can I travel during appeal?

Tags: visa-refusals

I'm a US citizen married to a British citizen for 12 years. My settlement visa for the 5 year partner route was refused because the immigration officer did not feel the documentation I provided proved our income/savings is high enough. It is and I will be submitting an appeal. My question is: can I visit the UK for up to 6 months while the appeal is pending? Since US citizens don't require a visitor visa for up to 6 months am I likely to be denied entry upon arrival without a visa due to the appeal? I plan to bring all documents including denial letter, marriage certificate, copies of appeal papers, return airfare, etc. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your problem is one of credibility. You've been denied a visa to live in Britain. If you show up at the airport looking for leave to enter as a visitor the border guard is going to assume that you're trying to bypass the system. It can be done, but you're going to have an uphill task persuading the border guards that you'll leave on time. If they don't bounce you immediately expect a very uncomfortable few hours while they question you and make a decision.

Comment: A long planned stay makes it harder, because you cannot have really strong ties to your home.

Comment: You might get help at our sister site [expatriates.se], but this smells like a question for an immigration lawyer.